# How to tell if any form from my app is in foreground

Tags: compact-framework

I'd like my compact framework application to show a notification bubble ONLY when it's running "in the background".  The application has several forms which may or may not be visible at any time.  I'd like the notification handler (which runs on background separate thread) to be able to tell if any form from my application is currently visible on the screen.

Is there a simple way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always [monitor when the Forms and Processes change](http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2008/08/13/determining-form-and-process-changes-in-windows-ce.aspx) from your app and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a way, there's a race condition here.  What will you do if you determine the form is in the foreground but at the same time the user has just moved something else into the foreground?  Your notification may be lost.