# Stop application running in background

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I have a .NET application running on a Smartphone.
I want a way for the application to close when it is pushed into the background.

I.e. if a user presses the off button once itll take them to the desktop.  The application is still running in the background though.

I want a way to detect that the application is no longer in the foreground and exit it.

I attempted doing this via the LostFocus event but it becomes complicated when option forms are loaded and isn't always reliable.

Can anyone offer suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433135/how-to-tell-if-any-form-from-my-app-is-in-foreground/433243

Answer (score 1):

I would listen to the [Form.Deactivate event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate.aspx) (or override the [Form.OnDeactivate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.ondeactivate.aspx) if you own the class) and check the [GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932991.aspx) function to determine if your form is in the background. If it isn't, then you know your form was sent to the background.

e.x.:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class Form1 : Form
{
[DllImport("coredll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("coredll")]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

protected override void OnDeactivate(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnDeactivate(e);

    //if the foreground window was not created by this application, exit this application
    IntPtr foregroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
    int foregroundProcId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindow, out foregroundProcId);
    using (Process currentProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
    {
        if (foregroundProcId != currentProc.Id)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exiting application.");
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the LostFocus event is probably the most reliable solution available.

If it were me, I would use Reflection to check to see if the *sender* of the LostFocus event were any of the Forms in my assembly. If not, exit.